# MySQL SPATIAL extension and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, spatial

I am need help..  How can i use spatial data with php.. I uploaded shape(esri geo) file to mysql as spatial data. and now i cant find any usefull information for get this data and echo it... Can your advise me any sites or information for this..

found this but don`t understand anything

```
SET @g = GeomFromText('LineString($longitude1 $latitude1,$longitude2 $latitude2)')
$query="SELECT AsBinary(SHAPE2), color FROM $layer WHERE MBRIntersects(SHAPE2,@g)";
...
$result=mysql_unbuffered_query($query);
```

[Spatial](http://early-medieval-gis.blogspot.com/2009/10/working-with-spatial-data-in-binary.html)

P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: http://we-love-programming.blogspot.in/2012/01/mysql-fastest-distance-lookup-given.html

Comment: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I advice not to use MySQL spatial extension if you want to analyse the data deeply. Better go for PostgreSQL. In MySQL the buffer function is available only in versions > 5.5 and MySQL doesn't have projection functions and SRID is stored only as a metadata.